# Add columns to csv using python prompt for data

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I found [this code](https://superuser.com/a/762464/477026) to split a CSV file using python.

I need to split 3,000,000 record CSV file when the column A changes.
I also need to add 2 more fields to the table

1. Blank (add a comma next to each line).
2. Add a date in the last field, but it should ask me for the date.

Would someone be able to help me add 2 thing to this code.

1. A prompt to add more fields
2. A prompt what should be in the field

   I am copying the code from the link included earlier

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import binascii
   import csv
   import os.path
   import sys
   from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
   from tkinter.simpledialog import askinteger

   def split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, keyfunc):
       csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
       csv_writers = {}
       for row in csv_reader:
           k = keyfunc(row)
           if k not in csv_writers:
                       csv_writers[k] = csv.writer(open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k),
                                                mode='w', newline=''))
           csv_writers[k].writerow(row)

   def get_args_from_cli():
       input_filename = sys.argv[1]
       column = int(sys.argv[2])
       dst_dir = sys.argv[3]
       return (input_filename, column, dst_dir)

   def get_args_from_gui():
       input_filename = askopenfilename(
           filetypes=(('CSV', '.csv'),),
           title='Select CSV Input File')
       column = askinteger('Choose Table Column', 'Table column')
       dst_dir = askdirectory(title='Select Destination Directory')
       return (input_filename, column, dst_dir)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       if len(sys.argv) == 1:
           input_filename, column, dst_dir = get_args_from_gui()
       elif len(sys.argv) == 4:
           input_filename, column, dst_dir = get_args_from_cli()
       else:
           raise Exception("Invalid number of arguments")
       with open(input_filename, mode='r', newline='') as f:
           split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, lambda r: r[column-1]+'.csv')
           # if the column has funky values resulting in invalid filenames
           # replace the line from above with:
           # split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, lambda r: binascii.b2a_hex(r[column-1].encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')+'.csv')
   ```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had it written in VBS

```
basename = "csv_split_"
hasHeader = True    'Change to False if there is no header.

argCnt = WScript.Arguments.Count
If argCnt < 1 Then
    WScript.Echo "Drag a CSV over this script to edit it."
    WScript.Quit
End If
flnm = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

set fs = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set cv = fs.OpenTextFile (WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
If Not fs.FileExists(flnm) Or LCase(fs.GetExtensionName(flnm)) <> "csv" Then
    WScript.Echo "This script is meant for CSV only."
    WScript.Quit
End If
fol = fs.GetParentFolderName(flnm)
customValue = InputBox("What should the last column contain?", "Column Info")

Set pat = New RegExp
pat.Global = True
pat.IgnoreCase = True
pat.Pattern = "^(""[^""]*""|[^,]*)?,"
recentCol = ""
csvCount = 1
header = ""
cnt = 0

While Not cv.AtEndOfStream
    cnt = cnt + 1
    row = cv.ReadLine
    If Right(row,1) <> "," Then: comma = ",": Else: comma = "": End If
    Set col1 = pat.Execute(row)
    col = col1.Item(0).Value
    sameFile = true
    If recentCol <> "" Then
        If col <> recentCol And cnt > 2 Then
            csvCount = csvCount + 1
            sameFile = false
        End If
    Else
        header = row & comma & """Off Peak"",""Effective Date""" 
        Set csv = fs.OpenTextFile(fol & "\" & basename & csvcount & ".csv", 8, True)    
    End If
    recentCol = col
    If Not samefile Then
        csv.close
        Set csv = fs.OpenTextFile(fol & "\" & basename & csvcount & ".csv", 8, True)
    End If
    If hasHeader And (1 = cnt or Not samefile) Then
        csv.WriteLine(header)
    Else
        csv.WriteLine(row & comma & ",""" & customValue & """")
    End if
Wend

csv.Close
```

Works Great!